# Unable to connect to CentOS from Windows server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos

I'm trying to connect to a CentOS virtual machine from a Windows 2012 server via the Jenkins CI engine. This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Connection refused: connect
SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused: connect".
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to :23
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:834)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:703)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:617)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1265)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:790)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:785)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can connect to the CentOS with PuTTY via ssh without any problems. Also, the firewall on the CentOS server is both disabled and down.

Can someone provide me with some information as to where I should go next in order to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I'm not versed in Jenkins but the error message `problem while connecting to :23` seems like the host/port information should have been where `:23` is, so perhaps your config is missing some info?

Comment: what do the server logs say?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" normally means that the host that you are trying to connect to isn't accepting connections on the requested port. In other words, the host isn't running an SSH server, or it is running an SSH server but the server isn't listening on port 23.

Note that you're trying to connect to port 23 here. SSH normally runs on port 22. Perhaps you've specified the wrong port number when configuring Jenkins?

Comment: I got the exact same error when using port 22 also. I've updated Jenkins and now I'm getting a completely different error which I suspect might be a Jenkins bug.